# How to find the minimal_circle of a given group of points based on the distances and proximity between a selected points

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

With the following expression presented in the question ([Creating the minimum convex hull that contains certain percentage of points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394835/creating-the-minimum-convex-hull-that-contains-certain-percentage-of-points-in-q)) it is possible to calculate the closest distances between groups of points:

```
array_sum ( 
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            $geometry, 
            limit:=2
        ),
        length (
            make_line (
                $geometry, 
                @element
            )
        )
    )
)
```

In the following screenshot I show the manual selection of the 20 points with the shortest distances from a total of 241 points (field "LONU"):

[image]

I would like to reuse this expression to build a Geometry Generator expression that:

1 → Selects the 20 shortest distances

2 → Finds a 4 groups of 3 closest points from this selection

3 → Draws the minimal_circle of each group

My goal is to reuse the above function to build an expression with the Geometry Generator that generates a geometry object like a minimal_circle from a 4 series of groups based on the distances and proximity between points. I show a screenshot with a simulation of the desired target:

[image]

My first approach (doesn't work):

```
with_variable(
    'min',
    array_sort (array_agg (LONU),0)[20],
with_variable(
    'value',
    4,
    make_line(
        $geometry,
        eval (
            'overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                filter:= LONU =' ||@min||' and || @value || ')[0]
    )
)
)
```

This expression doesn't work but I think it can give an idea of what I'm working on. Note that, at the moment, I try to draw a line but I would like to draw a `minimal_circle` or a `convex_hull`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the sum of the distances to nearest 3 points for each of the first 20 shortest distances from the `LONU` field.

```
if(
    array_find(
        array_agg($id, order_by:="LONU"),
        $id
    ) BETWEEN 0 AND 19,
    array_sum( 
        array_foreach(
            overlay_nearest( 
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                limit:=3
            ),
            distance(
                $geometry, 
                @element
            )
        )
    ),
    NULL
)
```

Only the first 20 distances will return a number the other lines will get a NULL value.

And now take the four groups. Use this in the Geometry by expression tool to create the final polygons.

```
if(
    array_find(
        aggregate(
            'Point layer name / id', -- set here point layer name
            'array_agg',
            $id,
            filter:=not ("distance 20" is NULL) -- replace distance 20 with the name of the field where you stored the past calculation
            order_by:="distance 20" -- set here the name of the field where you stored the past calculation
        ),
        $id
    ) BETWEEN 0 AND 3,
    minimal_circle(
        collect_geometries(
            overlay_nearest(
                'Point layer name / id', -- set here point layer name
                $geometry,
                limit:=4
            )
        )
    ),
    NULL
)
```

this all the features of the original layer but only the 4 groups will have geometry, so you can remove the remaining records with the remove null geometries tool.

Comment: A proposed solution that captures exactly the essence of the target I was looking for: a vector visualization model of hotspots, where there is a higher density of activity